# Multiple JOIN and OR in WHERE clause MySQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to optimize a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.t3_id = t3.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t4 ON t3.t4_id = t4.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 t5 ON t3.t5_id = t5.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table6 t6 ON t1.t6_id = t6.id
WHERE (t1.attribute1 = ? OR t2.attribute2 = ?)
AND t1.active = 1
AND t1.status <> 10
```

what I saw in the logs is that what takes most is the OR in the WHERE clause (with the OR the query takes ~1s for its execution, while without it it takes around ~400 ms with the data that I've sampled from the DB).

I'm looking for alternatives to get the same results without taking much time (also, performance decreases if many queries are executed concurrently).

I've tried replacing the OR with an union subquery with a join between t1 and t2 (I'm working with MySQL 5.7):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.attribute1 = ?
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.attribute2 = ?
) AS joined
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON joined.t3_id = t3.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t4 ON t3.t4_id = t4.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 t5 ON t3.t5_id = t5.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table6 t6 ON joined.t6_id = t6.id
WHERE joined.active = 1
AND joined.status <> 10
```

But I'd like to know if there is a better approach for optimizing the query.

EDIT: active, status, attribute1 and attribute2 are indexed as well as the ids.

Comment: `SELECT *` -- Are you sure you want all column from all tables?

Comment: yes, at the moment, the majority of the tables won't have more than 4 columns (table1 has 8)

Comment: Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation by query engines per textbooks in general & DBMS manual in particular--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. Appropriate research is expected for questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The following index can increase the performance of the first query, as long as your are not selecting too many rows (ideally less than 1000 rows):

```
create index ix1 on table1 (attribute1, active, status, t2_id);
```

Add this index. If it's still slow, add the execution plan to your question.

Comment: How does this help with `table2.attribute2`? The problem is that `OR` conditions can't use both indexes.

Comment: @Barmar `table2.attribute1` should work as an Nested Loop Join (NLJ). That should be cheap if the number of rows retrieved from the index is low.

Comment: @brhls If columns are indexed separately that won't help this query. The key issue here is to have a single composite index.

Comment: I'll try creating the composite index and I'll let you know (not expecting to get many results). Thanks!